# upload file in background, service?

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I need to upload a file to a server in background, i make this in asynctask, but, if i dont have internet, i want to upload later.
Actually, if there isnt network, asynctask crashes.

```
request.addProperty(file);

            envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
            new MarshalBase64().register(envelope); // serialization

            envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.ENC;
            envelope.bodyOut = request;

            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
            envelope.implicitTypes = true;

            HttpTransportSE transporte = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            transporte.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
            transporte.debug = true;

            try {
                transporte.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

What should be?A service that check the internet conection and when is on, upload the file? Other idea?

Anyone has a example please? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just check the coneection with this method

```
public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);



        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting())
        return true;
        return false;

        }
```

like

```
  internetconnection= isOnline();
    if(internetconnection==true){
    //performtask
    }
```

then you have to create broad cast reciever like
create a broad cast reciever and use this

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
```

in manifest 
it will run when ever there is internet state is change. in this check if it is online then upload the image

Comment: Yes, but if is offline, i want to upload the file later..And how can a i do it this¿?